# How can I access a factory from a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-show

I have some navbar items that should only be shown if the user is authenticated. Simplified view below:

**NAVBAR**

```
<body ng-controller="mainController as main">...
    <li ng-show="main.isSecretAgent"><a href="#secret">THIS IS A SECRET</a></li>
</body>
```

**FACTORY**

```
tardis.factory('bgData', [function() {
    var persistentData = {
        isSecretAgent: false, 
    };
    return {
        checkIfSecretAgent: function(){
            return persistentData.isSecretAgent
        }
    }
}]);
```

**MAIN CONTROLLER**

```
tardis.controller('mainController',["$scope","bgData", 
    function($scope,bgData) {
        $scope.isSecretAgent = bgData.checkIfSecretAgent()
    }
]);
```

Assuming the `isSecretAgent` value set in `bgData` factory can possibly change in response to user actions, how can I set my `ng-show` to update based on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your ng-show using a function call:

```
<span ng-show="isSecretAgent()">Show me when I'm a secret agent</span>
```

Then every time a digest runs the value inside the factory will be checked. That's all you should need to do.

Except you should change your isSecretAgent to call the function as follows:

```
tardis.controller('mainController',["$scope","bgData", 
    function($scope,bgData) {
        $scope.isSecretAgent = bgData.checkIfSecretAgent
    }
]);
```

Rather than assigning to the function call, assign the function (remove the '()' at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a function this way ...

**NAVBAR**

```
<body ng-controller="mainController as main">...
    <li ng-show="main.isSecretAgent()"><a href="#secret">THIS IS A SECRET</a></li>
</body>
```

**MAIN CONTROLLER**

```
tardis.controller('mainController',["$scope","bgData", 
    function($scope,bgData) {
        $scope.isSecretAgent = function { 
          return  bgData.checkIfSecretAgent()
        }
    }
]);
```

Also it would be better if you use `ng-if` because in case of `ng-show` the element would be still present in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes ng-if is slow to change over due to the DOM manipulation and this can be ugly.

Comment: Between changing `ng-show` to a function and waiting for a digest like @PeterAshwell suggests and maandoo's solution, which is "better practice"?

Comment: @PeterAshwell Yeah there may be issues with ng-if like what you said and some scope problems as it creates its own scope but in case of authentication it would be better to use ng-if right ?

Comment: @Huey I guess we both did the same thing but I would prefer PeterAshwell's code because it looks simple and nice. I called a function which calls the factory function... he directly assigned that to a diff scope variable and called it.

Comment: With regards to auth probably not, it's not like ng-if actually hides the DOM. It's still sent to the client side in the directive code or the template.

Comment: @PeterAshwell Yeah but a normal user can't just see that via inspect element right.

Comment: Yep true. 'Better practice' regarding assigning functions vs calling them is it's probably slightly more efficient not to call two functions (the scope function calling the service one) since these functions get run every digest.